# How can I import and work with correlation matrix as the only data source in PCA and PCF in R

Tags: r, pca

I am new to R, and am working on a problem of *mporting and working with correlation matrix as the only data source in PCA and PCF in R

I have referred to stack overflow answer banks and even books, I could not find any hints, it make it like R only work with variables data file whereas in SAS you can simply input the correlation matrix and get the PCA and PCF result easily. Hope I am wrong.

I tried to look at stack overflow answer banks, and they are mostly about how to calculate the cor matrix or eigenvalue decomposition.

Below is my attempts:

setwd("D:/BlueHDD/MAQAB/RStudio/R/PCA/Intelligence")

> mydata <- read.csv("Intelligence.csv",na.strings = ".")
>
> head(mydata)

```
  X     M     P     C     E     H     F
1 M 1.000 0.620 0.540 0.320 0.284 0.370
2 P 0.620 1.000 0.510 0.380 0.351 0.430
3 C 0.540 0.510 1.000 0.360 0.336 0.405
4 E 0.320 0.380 0.360 1.000 0.686 0.730
5 H 0.284 0.351 0.336 0.686 1.000 0.735
6 F 0.370 0.430 0.405 0.730 0.735 1.000
```

> ii <- as.matrix(mydata[,2:7])
>
> rownames(ii)<- c ("M","P","C","E","H","F")
>
> colnames(ii)<- c ("M","P","C","E","H","F")
>
> head(ii)

```
      M     P     C     E     H     F
M 1.000 0.620 0.540 0.320 0.284 0.370
P 0.620 1.000 0.510 0.380 0.351 0.430
C 0.540 0.510 1.000 0.360 0.336 0.405
E 0.320 0.380 0.360 1.000 0.686 0.730
H 0.284 0.351 0.336 0.686 1.000 0.735
F 0.370 0.430 0.405 0.730 0.735 1.000
```

> myPCA <- eigen(ii)
>
> head(myPCA)

$values

```
[1] 3.3670861 1.1941791 0.5070061 0.3718472 0.3131559 0.2467257
```

$vectors

```
           [,1]       [,2]         [,3]        [,4]         [,5]        [,6]
[1,] -0.3677678 -0.5098401  0.266985551  0.72768020  0.047584025 -0.04178482
[2,] -0.3913477 -0.4092063  0.485916591 -0.66464527 -0.005392018 -0.03872816
[3,] -0.3719504 -0.3825819 -0.831626240 -0.15204371 -0.003331423 -0.02352388
[4,] -0.4321872  0.3748248  0.021531885  0.06531777 -0.742970281 -0.34056682
[5,] -0.4219572  0.4214599  0.002730054  0.01174474  0.665109730 -0.44922966
[6,] -0.4565228  0.3288196  0.023032686  0.03473540  0.057617669  0.82365511
```

> myPCA$values

```
[1] 3.3670861 1.1941791 0.5070061 0.3718472 0.3131559 0.2467257
```

> myPCA$vectors

```
           [,1]       [,2]         [,3]        [,4]         [,5]        [,6]
[1,] -0.3677678 -0.5098401  0.266985551  0.72768020  0.047584025 -0.04178482
[2,] -0.3913477 -0.4092063  0.485916591 -0.66464527 -0.005392018 -0.03872816
[3,] -0.3719504 -0.3825819 -0.831626240 -0.15204371 -0.003331423 -0.02352388
[4,] -0.4321872  0.3748248  0.021531885  0.06531777 -0.742970281 -0.34056682
[5,] -0.4219572  0.4214599  0.002730054  0.01174474  0.665109730 -0.44922966
[6,] -0.4565228  0.3288196  0.023032686  0.03473540  0.057617669  0.82365511
```

The problem now in the vector, all the "+" and "-" are opposite !

---

Also, from here, I don't know how to get the loading matrix. I tried the below but fails:

```
fit <- princomp(ii)

summary(fit) # print variance accounted for 

loadings(fit) # pc loadings 

plot(fit,type="lines") # scree plot 

fit$scores # the principal components

biplot(fit)
```

Comment: Can you give a little more detail, maybe an example?  eigendecomposition of a correlation matrix *is* (scaled) PCA ...

Comment: Understood eigendecomposition of a correlation matrix is (scaled) PCA.

Comment: My problem is that the only data source is a correlation matrix. And I could not find the way to import it in R and manipulate it in R.

Comment: Below is my attempts:

Answer (score 1):

You can perform PCA in R with the `princomp` function. The documentation says that if you supply the argument `covmat` it will compute the principal components from the covariance matrix. But it also works to use this argument with the correlation matrix.

Here is a simple example using the iris data.

```
## principal components from the original data
princomp(iris[,1:4], cor=T)
Standard deviations:
   Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3    Comp.4 
1.7083611 0.9560494 0.3830886 0.1439265
```

Now suppose that you only have a correlation matrix

```
## from correlation matrix
CM = cor(iris[,1:4])
myPCA = princomp(covmat=CM)
myPCA
Standard deviations:
   Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3    Comp.4 
1.7083611 0.9560494 0.3830886 0.1439265
```

You get the same answer either way.  If you want the loadings, they are stored in the myPCA structure.

```
myPCA$loadings

Loadings:
             Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
Sepal.Length  0.521  0.377  0.720  0.261
Sepal.Width  -0.269  0.923 -0.244 -0.124
Petal.Length  0.580        -0.142 -0.801
Petal.Width   0.565        -0.634  0.524

               Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
SS loadings      1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
Proportion Var   0.25   0.25   0.25   0.25
Cumulative Var   0.25   0.50   0.75   1.00
```

Comment: iris.csv is an original variable dataset. My problem is I only have the correlation matrix. And I could not find the way to import it in R and manipulate it in R.

Comment: Yes,  but CM is just a correlation matrix.